# postgresql split_part - how to split after the first split key

Tags: postgresql, text, split

given the text string

```
foo.bar.baz
```

how do I use split_part function of postgresql to get the rest after the first dot?

I want to extract from this text the next 2 texts:

```
foo
bar.baz
```

split_part requires number of part as argument so

```
split_part('foo.bar.baz', ''.', 2);
```

returns

```
bar
```

but not `bar.baz`

how do I get this using this function, or any other available function?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably use the regex form of substring:

```
substring('foo.bar.baz' from E'[^.]*\\.(.+)$')
```

This matches any number of non-. characters, then a dot, then any number of characters. Because the last part is in brackets it is captured and returned.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(tx_nome, 1, STRPOS(tx_nome, ' ')) as first_name
    , SUBSTR(tx_nome, (STRPOS(tx_nome, ' ') + 1)) as last_nome
FROM my_table [...]
```